# Sorting the name of book by alphabetical order (without Comparable or Comparator interfaces)

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I came across a problem while practising Java.

I have a class *Book* which stores the following information:

> id (int), author and title

and I have another class *BookShelf* which store a collection of books using a Vector/ArrayList and have the following methods:

> addBook: takes in a book object as input, adds the object into the bookshelf, method returns nothing.
>
> returnListOfBooks: takes in no argument and returns a Vector/ArrayList of all books sorting by title in alphabetical order.
>
> returnListOfBooksByAuthor: takes in author as input and returns a Vector/ArrayList of books by that author

My question is, how do I create the method *returnListOfBooks* and sort them by title in alphabetical order?

**I have to implement the sorting and are not allowed to use Java's sorting mechanisms. **
Is there a way I can use this sorting using a `for` loop???

I will also have to do the following and sort in alphabetical order in the main driver program:

> • Call the method to return the list of books by author from the BookShelf object.
>
> • Traverse the list of books and print them one by one.
>
> • Number of unique books.

How do I do so?

I'm new to java so i'm not quite good at it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You want to use a Comparator: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm

Comment: You need to implement two separator `Comparator` for sorting the books by `title` and `author`.

Comment: @YoungHobbit I am not allowed to use Java's sorting mechanisms

Comment: You asked the same question 9 days ago -> vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: Please do put some efforts before putting any problem here, When it is duplicate you should have done some work by yourself.

Comment: @YoungHobbit None of the answers on the previous post answered my question. I've put in an effort to do some research however I was not able to find any solid answers. I have also edited that post before to be similar to this post prior to posting this post but I am new to this forum and I was not sure if an old post will get noticed, thus, after much consideration, I decided to post a new post.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was written **before** the title changed to *"(without Comparable or Comparator interfaces)"*.

You could implement a Comparator like so:

```
class TitleComparator implements Comparator<Book> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Book a, Book b) {
        return a.title.compareToIgnoreCase(b.title);
    }
}
```

Then you can just:

```
Collections.sort(books, new TitleComparator());
```

And your books will be sorted according to `title` in lexicographical order.

Comment: I am not allowed to use Java's sorting mechanisms (that includes `Comparator`)

Answer (score 0):

> As you are not allowed to implement/use `Comparable or Comparator`.

I would suggest the following:

```
private ArrayList<Book> sortedByTitleBooks;
private ArrayList<Book> sortedByAuthorBooks;
```

Maintain two more lists of books internally, which will hold the books in sorted manner. Implement a `insertion sort` for that. Now, every time you `addBook(Book)` a book to the `listOfBooks`, add the same book to other lists also.

Now you can directly return the sorted books list from each of the respective method.

---

You can use the `compareTo(String)` from the String class for comparison.

Here is the implementation for sorting the books using `author` name.

```
public void addBook(Book a){
  listOfBooks.add(a);
  sortByAuthor(a); // add the book into sortedByAuthor list as well
}

// insertion sorting
public void sortByAuthor(Book book) {
  if (sortedByAuthorBooks.isEmpty()) {
    sortedByAuthorBooks.add(book);
    return;
  }

  int size = sortedByAuthorBooks.size()-1;
  System.out.println(size);
  int index = 0;
  boolean inserted = false;
  while(index <= size) {
    Book b = sortedByAuthorBooks.get(index);
    int result = b.getAuthor().compareTo(book.getAuthor());
    if (result >= 0) {
      System.out.println(result);
      sortedByAuthorBooks.add(index, book);
      inserted = true;
      break;
    }
    index++;
  }
  if (!inserted) {
    sortedByAuthorBooks.add(book);
  }
}
```

Comment: How would `insertion sort` work however? I know how to use `insertion sort` with integer only and not Strings... Would be great if you can help me implement it minimally.

Comment: I have provided you the implementation for `author`, you can write a similar for the `title`.